# Return count of the child of child in C#

Tags: c#

I have a Application Object that has Applicant object in it. Applicant objects has Employments Object that has all information about the Employment (name,address,...) this can be 0 or 2,3,4,... How I can get the Count of Emp for 1 Application? So in this case in picture it had to return 4. But my code is returning 2 as it is returning the count for each Applicant not Application.

[image]

This is my code:

```
 public void InsertApplication(Application application)
    {
        if (application.Applicants != null)
        {
            foreach (var item in application.Applicants)
            {
                if (item.Employments != null)
                {
                    application.NumberOfEmployments = item.Employments.Count();
                }
            }
        }
        creditApplicationsContext.Applications.Add(application);
    }
```

This is Application Object:

```
  public class Application
    {
      public int Id { get; set; }
      public virtual ICollection<Applicant.Applicant> Applicants { get; set;    }
      public int? NumberOfEmployments { get; set; }
```

This is Applicant object:

```
 public class Applicant
{

    public int Id { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Employment> Employments { get; set; }
      ....
     }
```

and this is Employment Object:

```
  public class Employment
  {

    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string EmployerName { get; set; }
    public string EmployerPhoneNumber { get; set; }
    public Applicant Applicant { get; set; } 
     .....
    }
```

Comment: consider changes this `application.NumberOfEmployments = item.Employments.Count();` to `application.NumberOfEmployments += item.Employments.Count();` in case application.NumberOfEmployments starts at 0 and nobody will add or remove items from it. In all other case you could consider making it a life count and simply iterating your collections each time you ask for the object, or use ObservableCollections and tracking the changes through the INotifyCollectionChanged events

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get the total number of Number of employments consider this change in your code:

```
public void InsertApplication(Application application)
{
    if (application.Applicants != null)
    {
        foreach (var item in application.Applicants)
        {
            if (item.Employments != null)
            {
                application.NumberOfEmployments += item.Employments.Count();
            }
        }
    }
    creditApplicationsContext.Applications.Add(application);
}
```

In this way you have the total number of employments.
I think your code return 2 because is the number of the employments of the last application.

Answer (score 5):

If I'm understanding your structure properly, you should be able to use a fairly simple `SelectMany` and `Count`:

```
application.Applicants.SelectMany(a => a.Employments).Count();
```

Answer (score 2):

Well, you were nearly there, the problem is you're replacing the value for each child node, instead of adding it.

Change to this:

```
public void InsertApplication(Application application)
{
    application.NumberOfEmployments = 0;

    if (application.Applicants != null)
    {
        foreach (var item in application.Applicants)
        {
            if (item.Employments != null)
            {
                application.NumberOfEmployments += item.Employments.Count();
            }
        }
    }
    creditApplicationsContext.Applications.Add(application);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

`SelectMany` could help:

```
application.Applicants.SelectMany(x => x.Employments).Count();
```

Answer (score 2):

You can add a method to Get number of applications and use `SelectMany`

```
 public class Application
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public virtual ICollection<Applicant> Applicants { get; set; }
        public int? NumberOfEmployments { get; set; }

        public int GetNumberOfApplications()
        {
            return this.Applicants.SelectMany(x => x.Employments).Count();
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

```
application.NumberOfEmployments =
    application.Sum(app1 => app1.Applicants.Sum(app2 => app2.Employments.Count()));
```